# Displaying long text in Bootstrap tooltip

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I'm trying to display a bit of long text in a twitter bootstrap tooltip.  As you can see in the picture below, things aren't going smashingly.  Does anyone have an easy fix for text that overflows the bootstrap tooltip?

[image: tooltip overflow]

EDIT (added requested code):

In my controller:

```
<a href='" + Url.Action("Index", "PP", new {id = productRow.ProductGuid, area = ""}) + "' " + 
          ((blTruncated) ? "class='auto-tooltip' title='" + productRow.ProductName.Replace("'", "") : "") + "'>" + 
           productName + "</a>
```

In my view:

```
$('.auto-tooltip').tooltip();
```

Comment: Can you please show the code that you're using?

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 code added

Answer (score 98, accepted):

I'm not quite sure about your code,
here is an example with a long tool-tip value:

**Element:**

```
 <a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas bibendum ac felis id commodo. Etiam mauris purus, fringilla id tempus in, mollis vel orci. Duis ultricies at erat eget iaculis.">Hover here please</a>
```

**Js:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("a").tooltip({
    'selector': '',
    'placement': 'top',
    'container':'body'
  });
});
```

**Css:**

```
/*Change the size here*/
div.tooltip-inner {
    max-width: 350px;
}
```

Demo: [on JsBin.com](http://jsbin.com/UKiCeSE/187)

---

Apprently you can only change the `.tooltip-inner` in Bootstrap 4, thanks @Felix Dombek

```
.tooltip-inner { max-width: ... }
```

Comment: @funerr: Why not using `div.tooltip-inner { max-width: none; }`? Then it's never bounded anymore?!

Comment: @algorhythm because you probably want the tooltip text to wrap at some point.

Comment: what if title text is too long and without space. Then this condition will also fail.

Comment: Just setting `.tooltip-inner { max-width: ... }` works in **Bootstrap 4**!

Answer (score 33):

As hinted at [in the documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#callout-tooltip-multiline), the easiest way to ensure that your tooltip does not wrap at all is to use

```css
.tooltip-inner {
    max-width: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

With this, you don't have to worry about dimension values or anything like that. Main problem being if you have a super long line of text it will just go off of the screen (as you can see in the [JSBin Example](http://jsbin.com/nihido/edit?css,output)).

Comment: I removed the `white-space:nowrap;` and entered in a 1,000 character tooltip.  It worked okay in Firefox (but the issue has always been with IE's 512 limit), so when I tried it in IE, it hung up my cursor and spiked my CPU - no tooltip appeared.  Crazy!  All that from a tooltip.  Too bad I cannot embed a link to more info (that could pop-out more info) in the tooltip.

Answer (score 7):

You could use this source for better results:

```
.tooltip-inner {
 word-break: break-all;
}
```

[image]

Comment: `word-wrap: break-word;` may better

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative to styling the `.tooltip-inner` in a stylesheet you can add styles directly to the [tooltip](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips) by modifying the template of the tooltip.

This is probably not a good idea in most cases since you would be applying styles directly to the element, but it's worth noting that this is possible for those few cases where this is the only option or for some reason is the best option.

```
$(selector).tooltip({
  title: "Lorem ipsum ...",
  template: '<div class="tooltip" role="tooltip"><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-inner" style="max-width: none;"></div></div>',
});
```

Or, as an attribute:

```
<span
  data-toggle="tooltip"
  title="Lorem ipsum ..."
  data-template='<div class="tooltip" role="tooltip"><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-inner" style="max-width: none;"></div></div>'
  >Some abbreviation</span>

$(function(){
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

`template` option:

> Base HTML to use when creating the tooltip.
>
> The tooltip's `title` will be injected into the `.tooltip-inner`.
>
> `.tooltip-arrow` will become the tooltip's arrow.
>
> The outermost wrapper element should have the `.tooltip` class.

Defaults to:

```
'<div class="tooltip" role="tooltip"><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-inner"></div></div>'
```

As an alternative, you can add your own class to the template and style the custom class.

```
$(selector).tooltip({
  title: "Lorem ipsum ...",
  template: '<div class="tooltip" role="tooltip"><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-inner my-custom-tooltip"></div></div>',
});

.my-custom-tooltip {
  max-width: none;
}
```

Comment: This suit better for me. Coz I dont want to effect my whole system but only on particular case