# How do I style just one specific angular-ui-bootstrap tooltip to be wider?

Tags: css, angular-ui-bootstrap

In my AngualrJS application we use angular-ui-bootstrap tooltips.

I have one tooltip that needs to accommodate long text.
The answer to SO question [Displaying long text in Bootstrap tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18517483/displaying-long-text-in-bootstrap-tooltip) shows me how to make tooltips go wider...

... but what if I don't want to make *all* tooltips wider, just **one specific tooltip?**

(Notes: AngularJS 1.2.24, jQuery available... but I'd rather just be able to **apply a style to that single tooltip** than get more complicated)

Comment: Why don't you accept your own answer ?

Comment: @Sampath ha, thanks, missed that : )

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If on the other hand you have `tooltip-append-to-body="true"`, you can use the following modified version of @Daryn's code

CSS

```
.tooltip-400max .tooltip-inner {
  max-width: 400px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="element1"
  tooltip-append-to-body="true"
  tooltip-class="tooltip-400max"
  tooltip="{{ model.longTooltip }}">Text</div>
<div>More page content</div>
```

Comment: This is now a better answer than my original, due to introduction of `tooltip-class` available in angular-ui v0.13.0 in summer 2015

Comment: This works for `popover` as well; just use `popover-class`.

Answer (score 10):

As long as you don't have `tooltip-append-to-body="true"`, you can use the following CSS (in this example, making the tooltip max width 400px):

CSS

```
.tooltip-400max + .tooltip .tooltip-inner {
  max-width: 400px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="element1"
     class="tooltip-400max"
     tooltip="{{ model.longTooltip }}">Text</div>
<div>More page content</div>
```

---

The key in the CSS above is the *adjacent sibling selector*, `+`.

That's because, as you probably know, when you hover over *element1*, the tooltip is inserted as a div **after** *element1*, approximately like this:

```
<div id="element1"
     class="tooltip-400max"
     tooltip="{{ model.longTooltip }}">Text</div>
<div class="tooltip fade in" and other stuff>...</div>
<div>More page content</div>
```

Thus the CSS selector `.tooltip-400max + .tooltip` will select only this inserted tooltip, which is an adjacent sibiling. The descendant `.tooltip-inner` max-width styling will not affect all tooltips, only tooltips for elements with `tooltip-400max` class.

Comment: @das what property did you adjust, `width` or `max-width`? BTW To debug your styling, I like to temporarily add `tooltip-trigger="click"` to the element so the tooltip will stay visible, allowing me to try different styles in the browser developer tools.

Comment: Another quick option for debugging is right clicking on the tooltip and then clicking on the developer console (works in Chrome anyway)

Comment: I've changed the accepted answer to @TMG. As TMG points out, `tooltip-class` is now available (introduced in v0.13.0 last summer) and that's a way clearer way to apply the styling. This answer still applies for anyone using ui-boostrap v0.12 or lower.